# How to execute a task when specific execution conditions apply in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working with Gradle Tasks and I am wondering how can I make this pseudo-code-task sequene

```
task MAIN
 if fileA exists
  execute taskA
 else if fileB exists
  execute taskB
 else
  log a warning and cancel the build
```

Now `fileA` and `fileB` are dynamic, this means during one `./gradew :app:MAIN` the file can be there, and the next run it can be gone. I also want to have this scipt this dynamic without executing a `gradle sync` in between

#### Sidenotes

- I am working in an Android Studio environment
- These files are moved around within the tasks, so they are modified a lot
- The project is massive and gradle sync takes a long time, so putting these conditions (task dependencies) in the configuration phase is not an option.